# OpenCL host readable "thread local" memory

Tags: opencl

I need (host readable) thread local memory for my OpenCL kernel. Let's look at an example:

```
//Assume #threads is known to be 8
double threadLocalScalar[8] = {}; //1 scalar per thread
for(some range in parallel)
    threadLocalScalar[getThreadId()] += 1;
```

This is a basic "thread local memory" solution. A vector of length #threads and the usage of function getThreadId().

Now, I need to do the same (or anything that works the same) in OpenCL. My research so far is to use the function get_group_id(0) to get the work group id (and maybe for simplicity use work group size = 1). This way I know what "thread" is executing and can modify the correct part of a global memory vector.

However, I don't know how many "threads" are going to be created. So I can't determine how much global memory I need for the threadLocalScalar vector. How can I know this? Or, do you know any better solution? Is my research even correct?

Note:
The problem with using local memory is that I cannot read it from host. Otherwise I could easily use local memory and work_grop_size = 1 (only 1 "thread" per work_group meaning the local memory is "thread local".

Comment: get_num_groups(dim) seems to tell me how many "threads" will be used, but this function is a kernel function, I need to know this in advance in the host code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need shared local memory if adjacent work items need access to the same global memory locations; using shared local memory means you only have to read the global value once per work group instead of multiple times.

Your code example (`threadLocalScalar[getThreadId()] += 1`) doesn't do that, it just increments a memory location per work item (independent work), so you don't need shared local memory. Just increment your global memory based on the global_id(0).

Comment: Thank you for participating. The problem is that the kernel I have kind of do a reduction of the larger input data into #threads scalars.

So when i have a range that is 1 million, I should end up with #threads or "#cores" scalars that the host is then summing up in serial.

So for each global_id I need to know what "thread id" this item is being executed using. I need to know this so that I can add my result to the correct scalar (using no synchronization or data races).

Comment: Okay so I think I kind of get this now. When you do reductions using OpenCL, it's not as well defined how many "threads" will be used. So instead of querying "whats the perfect amount of threads" you actually decide for yourself.

If I have 1 million items to reduce, I could actually decide for myself how many segments I want to use. On the CPU this is probably #threads * some scalar but on the GPU, it's not that clear what is a "thread" and not. So you just have to guess / tweak based on some of the device caps. It's not perfect but it'll work.